# Redux API fetch does not re-fetch new data even when the data changes until page refresh in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, rest

I new to redux I've created a rest API when pulls a list of users in a database and has other various API endpoints which help interact with this database like editing users information etc
I used redux to make a get request to get the user which displays this user's information when the page loads but when I use to try to make updates to the data the changes take work but I have to reload my application to see these changes. My question is, is there a way whereby I can automatically make my fetch request fetch the new updates so it can update the state whenever changes are made I've tried passing various parameters like the loading state as callback functions in my useEffect hook but that doesn't work I ended up with an infinite loop I'd really appreciate the help thank you here's my code below

```
import api from "../util/api";
export const userDataAction = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: 'REQUEST_USER_DATA'})
        api().get('api/user')
        .then(response => {
            if (!Cookies.get('Authentication_cookies')) {
                throw Error('Unauthorized')
            }
                const data = response.data;
                const sessionCookies = Cookies.get('Authentication_cookies');
                dispatch({ type: 'ACCESS_GRANTED_DATA', data, sessionCookies })
        })
        .catch((errors) => {
            // const error = errors.response.data.message
            dispatch({type: 'ACCESS_DENIED_DATA', errors})
        })
    }
}
```

this is my fetch request

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { CookiesAuthCheck } from '../../cookieTokens/useCookies';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userDataAction } from '../../actions/userDataAction';

function AuthGuard({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    const cookie = CookiesAuthCheck();
    const state = useSelector((state)=> state.authData);
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const userData = state.userData;
    useEffect(() => {   
       dispatch(userDataAction())
    }, [dispatch])
    return <Route {...rest} render={(props) =>{
        if(!cookie){
            return <Redirect to='/login'/>
        }
            return <Component {...props} userData={userData}/>
    }}/>
}
export default AuthGuard
```

this is where the action was dispatched to fetch the user and pass down as props to various routes

```
const initState = {
    loading: true,
    userData: null,
    AuthCookies: null,
    error: null,

}
const userReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_USER_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case 'ACCESS_DENIED_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            }

        case 'ACCESS_GRANTED_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                userData: action.data,
                error: null
            }
}
}
```

this is the reducer

Comment: You need to be more specific to when you want to make the call again. You have just said when data changes, but what data. Your component needs to make the call every-time something happens, you need to design what that something is.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the userData object which in my reducer that the data is the data I want it to re fetch and update the old state data with the new change that was made

Comment: The reducer is only updated when the action is called. So I am having trouble understanding how it would change without the data being refetched. If you mean to refetch when the actual data in the database changes there is no way for the database change to cause a refetch on the frontend.

Comment: I have dispatched the action if you look at the second code script where I said the action was dispatched and the data was passed as a prop to other components

Comment: I’ve already created api end points which update the data and the updates work according to my question I can get the data but I’d need to reload the page again

Answer (score 0):

It seems because you have declared userData as a const once there is no reason for the component to rerender.

*Note it is difficult to be sure as I can't test your code.

Try the below code changes.

**Option 1**

Change

```
const userData = state.userData;
```

to

```
const { userData } = useSelector((state => state.authData)
```

Alternatively you can add a new useEffect hook and a state value. These will run everytime the `state` variable changes and update a state value. The state value will then trigger a rerender.

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setUserData(state.authData.userData);
}, [state])
```

Comment: thank you very  but it didn't work ive tried the solution you provided still the same result

Comment: So the data is updating but is not being passed down to the component?

Comment: Yes it’s updating on the server side I’m looking for a solution where I don’t have to refresh my application before the changes update in my reducer state...want it to be automatic

Comment: You should investigate WebSocket connections then, Rest API's cant update the frontend without a request. This is how Stackoverflow is able to send you notifications without you refreshing your page.